# "things are not working yet" vs. "things do not work yet"

Tags: present-continuous

I've read the question ["It works" vs "It is working"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13418/it-works-vs-it-is-working), but how about the same issue if you add "yet" at the end:

1. Some things do not work yet
2. Some things aren't working yet

Which would you prefer and why? I'd prefer 2.

Comment: Both are valid English statements.  Why do you prefer 2 and by what criteria are you concerned regarding their usage?  Why is this important to you?

Comment: By my "preference" of 2 I just meant to say that 2 feels more correct to me. What is important to me is just that I don't use an incorrect phrase. :) If you say both are correct, that's good to know, thanks for your help.

Comment: They are both correct and I cannot think of a difference in meaning between them that I can quantify. You could argue for a slight difference in tone, as @CoolHandLouis has done, but that's about it. The meaning is the same and both are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differences in tone and formality.  The first is more formal and could perhaps be used more emphatically:

Captain:  "We need to prepare to lift off this planet immedately!".
Engineer:  "Captain, some things **do not** work yet and if we lift off now we run the risk of engine failure!"

Mary (Coworker 1): "Hey Joe, how's that code subsystem coming along?  I need to use that API as soon as possible."
Joe (Coworker 2): "Well, some things aren't working yet, but that won't affect you.  I'll go ahead and publish it to our common work area."
Mary: "Thanks!"
Joe: "No problem!"

Comment: Great. Thanks for the examples. My current case matches the second example almost literally. :)

Comment: I'm skeptical -- "do not" sounds formal precisely because you didn't contract it to "don't." If you said "some things are not working yet" it would also come across as formal.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the context of use, just like the example right below this answer...so you can't decide on it very well,  I would definitely go for the second as well, it's something I would use

Comment: Welcome to ELL! 1) This strikes me as a Comment on CoolHandLouis' answer rather than an Answer in itself. If you leave it as an answer the mods may move or delete it. 2) In any case, it's dangerous to refer to 'below' and 'above'--the answers move around, depending on how many votes each gets.